# Error while deploying Angular 2 to Heroku

Tags: angular, heroku, angular2-aot

Need help deploying angular 2 app which was created using the angular-cli. My application runs on port 4200 locally and I have proxy settings that route my url requests to localhost:8080 where my backend server (spring-boot app) is running.

I have deployed my backend server to heroku successfully. Now I want to deploy my angular app to heroku as well.

While executing "ng build --aot -prod", the build fails with error "**ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Calling function 'ɵmakeDecorator', function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function, resolving symbol Injectable in /tmp/build_cc056824e4c062306cc02ac5a41c4dc8/node_modules/angular-datatables/node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts**".

Below is package.json file

```
{
  "name": "client-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng server --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "preinstall": "npm install -g http-server",
    "postinstall": "ng build --aot -prod"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "angular-datatables": "^4.1.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "datatables.net": "^1.10.15",
    "datatables.net-dt": "^1.10.15",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "ng2-uploader": "^2.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4",
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/datatables.net": "^1.10.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/jquery": "^2.0.45",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.5.0",
    "typescript": "~2.2.0"
  },
  "engines": {
  "node": "6.10.3",
  "npm": "3.10.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {

  }
}
```

and my proxy.conf.json file -

```
{
    "/api":{
    "target" : "http://localhost:8080",
    "secure" : false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check your Procfile - you need to create one like this

**Heroku needs a ProcFile to deploy it.**

ProcFile:

```
web: tsc && lite-server
```

The above is my configuration.

And then replace it with the line from package.json

**"start": "ng server --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",**

And change it to web: ng server --proxy-config proxy.conf.json
in the ProcFile
Your ProcFile should look like the below

```
web: ng-server --proxy-config proxy.conf.json
```

Push the changes on to the git of heroku as given below

```
git add .
git commit -m 'Procfile Updated'
git push heroku master
```

then type in the cli after the git commit is uploaded

heroku ps:scale web=1
Test run the app on your local machine

```
 heroku local web
```

If the app doesnt run properly

run

```
heroku logs
```

check your log output for any errors.

Finally if the app runs fine locally
then do

```
heroku open
```

This will run the app from the heroku cloud.

Hope that helps.